# why fat will store only in belly region

Tags: bellyfat

when we **overeat**, fat should store equally in every parts of the body

why it will store only in belly region **for some person**s ?

for some persons, if they **eat more with no workouts** also they look **slim**

for some persons, if they **eat less** , than also they look **fat** ?

Is it all depends on individuals ?

Comment: Genetics. Yes, it's an individual thing.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Thanks,  you can post your comment as answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into adrenoceptors – specifically alpha-2 and beta-2. These are receptors that control blood flow into/out of the fat cell, as well as cell metabolism (and a host of other biological functions not related to fat storage). Alpha-2 receptors are the nasty ones – areas around the hip and thighs (especially for woman), and the abdomen and low back (for men) have up to 10x the amount of alpha-2 receptors compared to beta-2. The alpha-2 receptor distribution is why it is extremely hard to lose fat around these areas, and why they are the last to go when losing weight; the alpha-2 receptors just won’t let the fat be released from the cell (and the lack of blood flow makes it hard to get the necessary fat-loss (really, fat-release) hormones (epinephrine/norepinephrine, catecholamines, and others) into the fat cell in the first place.) There are most likely evolutionary reasons for the distribution of these receptors (e.g., woman to support child bearing).

There are also biological reasons fat is not stored evenly around the body; but that’s beyond the scope of this answer.

Also, during normal activity during the day (and weeks/months/years), we are constantly storing and/or burning fat to support normal metabolic function (e.g., at night when we’re sleeping and in a fasted state we’ll burn fat). So, at least part of the uneven distribution of body fat is due to the fact that we store fat around the body when in a calorie surplus, but when we burn fat, it’s being taken from the face, arms, chest, legs, etc. preferentially, and not from the hip/thighs or abdomen/low back. Over time, this exacerbates the uneven distribution of fat around the body.

For a comprehensive examination of the above concepts, look into the work of Lyle McDonald. He goes into excruciating biological detail into the above concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Every person is different in terms of how many calories they burn each day and how fast their metabolism is.

1. People store fat first in different body parts. For example person A could store fat first in their belly and then their face. Person B could store fat first in their face and then their belly, its different for every person.
2. Neglecting metabolism, people who say they eat a lot and don't gain weight are not actually eating enough and vice versa. Best way is to count calories!

Comment: Thanks , so FILO - First In Last Out policy ..... well i dont have any fat in my body other than belly region, so i hope when i workout, initially fat will burn from belly region only right ?

Comment: There probably is fat on other parts of the body - but not as much as the belly region - but still yes, if you lose weight you will notice a smaller belly.

Comment: _"The only bad thing is the place where you first store fat is where it comes off last!"_ - care to explain this claim?

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29768/does-the-body-store-fat-in-a-first-in-last-outfilo-order, yeah it doesn't seem to be scientifically proven. Corrected answer.

Comment: @rrirower - I have looked for this corroboration as well, as I remember being taught that in my kinesiology classes. Haven't found it yet, but still looking as I believe it is a valid concept. Certainly plays true in my body, n=1.

Comment: @USer345738380 Lol it's just impossible to not have any fat in your other body regions. I suggest you looking up some basic scientific facts online. Fat is not just something bulging significantly on your belly.