# Does biking really reduce fats from thighs?

Tags: weight-loss, bicycling, fat, thigh

Is biking really reduce fat from thighs and make them not touch ? Or it transform fats from thigh to muscles and so they will stay at the same size ?

From [this link](https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/healthyliving/cycling-health-benefits), it seems that biking is useless:

> Research suggests you should be burning at least 8,400 kilojoules
>   (about 2,000 calories) a week through exercise. Steady cycling burns
>   about 1,200 kilojoules (about 300 calories) per hour.
>
> If you cycle twice a day, the kilojoules burnt soon add up. British
>   research shows that a half-hour bike ride every day will burn nearly
>   five kilograms of fat over a year.

Comment: I'm not sure what gauge they are using, but even 12 mph on a bike should burn ~ 600 calories an hour for a 180 lb person. Also related: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29768/does-the-body-store-fat-in-a-first-in-last-outfilo-order

Comment: and what about thigh fats ? I read that cardios done on legs help for it

Comment: Then they are wrong. The exercise you do has no effect on where your body gets fat from.

Answer (score 4):

Body part specific fat loss is not possible. A person gradually loses bodyfat from their entire body when fat is lost. Some body parts simply carry more fat than others, so acquiring a lower (total) body fat percentage is required to see progress in "stubborn" areas. What's more, fat loss is only ever the product of being in a caloric deficit. Exercise can certainly contribute to this (it also has many other benefits), but the biggest contributor by at least twice as much is what you put in your mouth.

Comment: So I just have a healthy lifestyle with healthy foods and exercise at least 30 min per day and I will get fit thighs ?

Comment: Terms like “healthy” and “fit” tend to be very subjective. A healthy diet can lead to weight loss, weight maintenance, or weight gain - how many calories you eat will determine what happens. By my definition, low body fat along with decent muscle development would qualify as (visually) fit. Without sufficient muscle mass, a low body fat percentage will lead to simply having skinny thighs, certainly not fit thighs. So to reach a goal of having fit thighs, you’ll want to potentially lose body fat (depending on how much you have), and also start including some muscle building exercises.

Comment: exactly what muscle building exercise I should do ?And I have 10.5 Kg of fats and my dietitian said that I have +0.00 fats and these 10.5 kg should stay in my body.