# Is it correct that walking is better than jogging to reduce thighs and inner thighs fats?

Tags: running, weight-loss, fat, walking, thigh

I've been doing sport, particularly, walking, for around 1 year. Each day, 7 days per week.

I didn't use a specific diet, but I cut eating any sort of sugars during the week, except for weekends, where I can treat myself.

The main problem is that I am not fat, I am 165 cm tall and weighing 56.6 kg, with regular shape, but the moment I sit down my thighs go very wide. I have big inner thighs.

So I decided to stop walking and do jogging instead, each day for 45 to 50 minutes.

But my thighs went slightly wider, as it become bigger. It is like someone inject them with air.

I went for a dietitian and said it is okay, but you should lift weight. I don't want big muscles, neither big thighs.

My scale test (the scale used at dietitians) shows that I have 7 kg of muscles in each leg, and 1.6 kg of fat.

After doing some [researches](https://www.rachaelattard.com/how-to-lose-inner-thigh-fat/), I found this article, which saying that reducing thigh fat should start with reducing overall body fat first, and afterwards, doing walking, and not running, to target the inner thighs:

> In all my experience, the best exercise for getting rid of inner thigh
>   fat is walking. Not running, swimming, cycling, elliptical, dancing,
>   etc. WALKING.
>
> I know it sounds too simple right?! But don’t underestimate it.
>   Walking is the absolute best exercise for getting rid of the excess
>   fat here.
>
> Unfortunately, though you need to do a lot of walking. By a lot, I
>   mean 10,000 steps per day (or 10kms if you can!) at least. I know this
>   can be time-consuming and lots of people don’t have this time.
>
> But the 10,000 steps doesn’t need to be done all at once. You can
>   accumulate these steps during the day.

[So is it correct that only walking](https://intothegloss.com/2013/08/the-walk-dont-run-exercise-theory-small-key-son-trainer/), for 40-50 minutes, 3 to 4 days per week with a low fat/sugars diet help reduce thigh perimeter and fat ?

Comment: The answer has not changed since you asked [this question about targeted fat loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/38795/does-biking-really-reduce-fats-from-thighs) last year.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't target fat loss. If you want to reduce fat on your thighs, you'll need to reduce fat over your entire body.** Where your body stores most fat is different for every individual and is genetically determined. Most common are around the stomach and the butt/legs.

If you do some weight lifting you won't become big and muscular out of no where, this takes time and effort. What it can do thought is tone your muscles a bit which can help shape your legs, this might be why your dietitian opted for some weight lifting.

Now, about the walking vs jogging part. There are some differences to take into account, **I would advice you to read [this question and answer(s)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-running-versus-walking)**

Comment: what are the weight lifting that I could do to just slim thighs without increases its size ?